# WSO2 Developer Studio Account Service Sample Missing Jars

Tags: jar, wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I am very much a newbie on WSO2, I am busy doing some proof of concept work. I seem to have a problem going through the samples in developer studio, I am sure its an easy fix but I cant find the problematic jars anywhere it seems.

I have setup the Account Service Example but the project cannot find any of the wso2 jars required (which I find a little odd). axiom-1.2.9-wso2v1.jar is an example.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

thanks
Paul

Comment: Is there a .pom file generated for the project?

Comment: All the required information/instructions are included in the README file of the sample.

Answer (score 3):

You have to build account service sample using maven to download dependencies